# how to show an Info dialog in the bottom right corner of the screen like Youtube

Tags: flutter

I need to show an info dialog in the bottom right corner of the screen; an example is when I upload a new video on Youtube, it shows something like this [dialog on Youtube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXdZR.jpg)
there is some Widget for something like this?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an overlay entry, give it the correct position and add it to the context.

```
var overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return YourWidget();
  }
);
```

Then add it to the context whenever needed :

```
Overlay.of(context)!.insert(overlayEntry!);
```

You could also use a Tooltip widget if what you want to show is just a text. Create a SizedBox() and position just below where you want to have the dialog, wrap it with a Tooltip widget. Give the tooltip a global key, set the trigger type to manual and whenever needed show it.

```
final key = GlobalKey<State<Tooltip>>(); 

Tooltip(
   key: key,
   message: your text
   child: SizedBox(),
   triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.manual,)
```

and show it with :

```
void showDialog(GlobalKey key) {
var tooltip = key.currentState;
tooltip?.ensureTooltipVisible();}
```